# This simple code doesn't run

Tags: javascript

it is very simple at the first look but the variable doesn't take the string as a text I guess, I don't know why? I am using notepad++

```js
    var cnextimage = "C:\Users\disley\Desktop\My Website\image\" ;
document.write(cnextimage);
```

Comment: You should escape backslashes using `\\ `  like  `c:\\myfolder`

Comment: Or you could just use /

Comment: why the downvotes? and thanks!

Comment: The reason this is happening is because "\" is used for [Escape Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaS‌​cript/Reference/Glob‌​al_Objects/String#Es‌​cape_notation) If you actually want a "\" inside a string and not act as escape notation you need to escape it using "\\"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\\` for a symbol `back-slash`. `\` is a reserved symbol. For example `\n` means a line break. When you write a `\` the engine waits for a special `character` like `n`. So to distinguish that you are using `back-slash` you need to use `\\` for it.

```js
var cnextimage = "C:\\Users\\disley\\Desktop\\My Website\\image\\";
document.write(cnextimage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly escape the slashes using a double-slash `\\` as a normal slash is a reserved character:

```
var cnextimage = "C:\\Users\\disley\\Desktop\\My Website\\image\\";
document.write(cnextimage);
```